# Why do the characters in the movie speak incorrect English?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery

For example: I heard this words in the movie: predefinite, Inbreathiate, trifled etc

Why do the characters in the movie 'Glass Onion: A Knives Out Mystery' (2022) speak incorrect English?

Comment: You heard _characters_ use those words or you heard **Miles** use non-words?   Miles is, as Benoit Blanc says, an idiot who is trying to pretend he's smart.

Comment: "Trifled" [is not incorrect English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/trifled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hesitate to answer for fear of spoiling the movie for you, because I wonder if you've watched the movie to the end, because this is a critical plot point described in detail by Blanc.

Only Miles uses made up or incorrectly used worlds.  Towards the end of the movie, Blanc uses this to illustrate that Miles is not the genius everyone assumes he is because of his successful career and money.  From the [script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery-2022.pdf):

> **[When they all first arrived, Miles:]
> MILES**
>
> Let's all embreathiate this moment.
>
> **BLANC**
>
> Not a real word. Kinda sounds like
> one. But just entirely made up.
> "Reclamation" IS a word - but it is
> the wrong word!
>
> **[When Miles is first showing them around:]
> MILES**
>
> This place is the reclamation of
> everything I've ever accomplished
>
> **BLANC**
>
> This entire day -
>
> **[Miles first confronting Blanc about the invitation:]
> MILES**
>
> ...the predefinite detective...
>
> **BLANC**
>
> a veritable minefield of
> malapropisms
>
> **[All lounging, Miles telling the Sweety Pants story:]
> MILES**
>
> ...the infraction point...

"trifled" on the other hand, is a valid English word used correctly by Blanc:

> BLANC
>
> Mr. Bron. I've learned through bitter
> experience that an anonymous
> invitation is not to be trifled with.

See definition in [Miriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trifle).

Answer (score 2):

> I heard this words in the movie: predefinite, Inbreathiate, trifled etc
>
> Why do the characters in the movie 'Glass Onion: A Knives Out Mystery' (2022) speak incorrect English?

Firstly, "trifled" is not incorrect English...

> **trifle**
>
> treat without seriousness or respect. -
> "he is not a man to be trifled with"

As for the other words, these are, indeed, incorrect English but *based* on an actual words.

In this case, I think you will find that they are only spoken by Miles who uses long words to imitate intelligence but **actually** gets them wrong because as Blanc says *"He's an idiot".*

Answer (score -2):

**Why not ?**

As stated in other answers, in this specific occurrence, it was used too impersonate a character that is trying to show an intelligence he did not possess, therefore it totally make sense he botches words.

But even the 'trying to look smart' part is not mandatory. Bad language can be used simply to show the lack of education, or a foreign origin (or in some medias, time displacement).
I'm pretty sure it is even an acknowledged trope.

In Game of throne, we even get it referenced in-world (but inverted) when Tywin Lannister call Aria off because she properly say 'My lord' instead of 'M'lord'